# Hive join table with itself many times

Tags: sql, hive, query-optimization, hiveql

I have a need to join a table with itself 13 times in Hive and this is acting really slow. I'm using Hive on Tez.

When I take a look at the Hive swim lane it seems that only Map tasks are executing and doing this sequentially, it seems that this is one of the reasons it takes so long.

[image]

One of the things that I suspect that could also be the problem is that I'm joining using 3 columns, but I'm not sure how can this influence the timing.

Is there a way to speed up execution of this query?

```
WITH merged AS (
SELECT
    mp_0.bp AS bp,
    mp_0.name as name,
    mp_0.country as country,

    mp_0.pos AS pos_0,
    mp_0.min_p AS min_p_0,
    mp_0.max_p AS max_p_0,

    mp_1.pos AS pos_1,
    mp_1.min_p AS min_p_1,
    mp_1.max_p AS max_p_1,

    mp_2.pos AS pos_2,
    mp_2.min_p AS min_p_2,
    mp_2.max_p AS max_p_2,

    mp_3.pos AS pos_3,
    mp_3.min_p AS min_p_3,
    mp_3.max_p AS max_p_3,

    mp_4.pos AS pos_4,
    mp_4.min_p AS min_p_4,
    mp_4.max_p AS max_p_4,

    mp_5.pos AS pos_5,
    mp_5.min_p AS min_p_5,
    mp_5.max_p AS max_p_5,

    mp_6.pos AS pos_6,
    mp_6.min_p AS min_p_6,
    mp_6.max_p AS max_p_6,

    mp_7.pos AS pos_7,
    mp_7.min_p AS min_p_7,
    mp_7.max_p AS max_p_7,

    mp_8.pos AS pos_8,
    mp_8.min_p AS min_p_8,
    mp_8.max_p AS max_p_8,

    mp_9.pos AS pos_9,
    mp_9.min_p AS min_p_9,
    mp_9.max_p AS max_p_9,

    mp_10.pos AS pos_10,
    mp_10.min_p AS min_p_10,
    mp_10.max_p AS max_p_10,

    mp_11.pos AS pos_11,
    mp_11.min_p AS min_p_11,
    mp_11.max_p AS max_p_11,

    mp_12.pos AS pos_12,
    mp_12.min_p AS min_p_12,
    mp_12.max_p AS max_p_12,

    mp_13.pos AS pos_13,
    mp_13.min_p AS min_p_13,
    mp_13.max_p AS max_p_13
FROM
    data.customers mp_0
    INNER JOIN  data.customers mp_1
        ON mp_0.name = mp_1.name
            AND mp_0.day = mp_1.day
            AND mp_0.identify = mp_1.identify
            AND mp_0.bp = mp_1.bp
            AND mp_1.position = 1
            AND mp_1.day <= 123456
            AND mp_1.day > 123456 - 8
    INNER JOIN  data.customers mp_2
        ON mp_0.name = mp_2.name
            AND mp_0.day = mp_2.day
            AND mp_0.identify = mp_2.identify
            AND mp_0.bp = mp_2.bp
            AND mp_2.position = 2
            AND mp_2.day <= 123456
            AND mp_2.day > 123456 - 8
    INNER JOIN  data.customers mp_3
        ON mp_0.name = mp_3.name
            AND mp_0.day = mp_3.day
            AND mp_0.identify = mp_3.identify
            AND mp_0.bp = mp_3.bp
            AND mp_3.position = 3
            AND mp_3.day <= 123456
            AND mp_3.day > 123456 - 8
    INNER JOIN  data.customers mp_4
        ON mp_0.name = mp_4.name
            AND mp_0.day = mp_4.day
            AND mp_0.identify = mp_4.identify
            AND mp_0.bp = mp_4.bp
            AND mp_4.position = 4
            AND mp_4.day <= 123456
            AND mp_4.day > 123456 - 8
    INNER JOIN  data.customers mp_5
        ON mp_0.name = mp_5.name
            AND mp_0.day = mp_5.day
            AND mp_0.identify = mp_5.identify
            AND mp_0.bp = mp_5.bp
            AND mp_5.position = 5
            AND mp_5.day <= 123456
            AND mp_5.day > 123456 - 8
    INNER JOIN  data.customers mp_6
        ON mp_0.name = mp_6.name
            AND mp_0.day = mp_6.day
            AND mp_0.identify = mp_6.identify
            AND mp_0.bp = mp_6.bp
            AND mp_6.position = 6
            AND mp_6.day <= 123456
            AND mp_6.day > 123456 - 8
    INNER JOIN  data.customers mp_7
        ON mp_0.name = mp_7.name
            AND mp_0.day = mp_7.day
            AND mp_0.identify = mp_7.identify
            AND mp_0.bp = mp_7.bp
            AND mp_7.position = 7
            AND mp_7.day <= 123456
            AND mp_7.day > 123456 - 8
    INNER JOIN  data.customers mp_8
        ON mp_0.name = mp_8.name
            AND mp_0.day = mp_8.day
            AND mp_0.identify = mp_8.identify
            AND mp_0.bp = mp_8.bp
            AND mp_8.position = 8
            AND mp_8.day <= 123456
            AND mp_8.day > 123456 - 8
    INNER JOIN  data.customers mp_9
        ON mp_0.name = mp_9.name
            AND mp_0.day = mp_9.day
            AND mp_0.identify = mp_9.identify
            AND mp_0.bp = mp_9.bp
            AND mp_9.position = 9
            AND mp_9.day <= 123456
            AND mp_9.day > 123456 - 8
    INNER JOIN  data.customers mp_10
        ON mp_0.name = mp_10.name
            AND mp_0.day = mp_10.day
            AND mp_0.identify = mp_10.identify
            AND mp_0.bp = mp_10.bp
            AND mp_10.position = 10
            AND mp_10.day <= 123456
            AND mp_10.day > 123456 - 8
    INNER JOIN  data.customers mp_11
        ON mp_0.name = mp_11.name
            AND mp_0.day = mp_11.day
            AND mp_0.identify = mp_11.identify
            AND mp_0.bp = mp_11.bp
            AND mp_11.position = 11
            AND mp_11.day <= 123456
            AND mp_11.day > 123456 - 8
    INNER JOIN  data.customers mp_12
        ON mp_0.name = mp_12.name
            AND mp_0.day = mp_12.day
            AND mp_0.identify = mp_12.identify
            AND mp_0.bp = mp_12.bp
            AND mp_12.position = 12
            AND mp_12.day <= 123456
            AND mp_12.day > 123456 - 8
    INNER JOIN  data.customers mp_13
        ON mp_0.name = mp_13.name
            AND mp_0.day = mp_13.day
            AND mp_0.identify = mp_13.identify
            AND mp_0.bp = mp_13.bp
            AND mp_13.position = 13
            AND mp_13.day <= 123456
            AND mp_13.day > 123456 - 8
WHERE
    mp_0.position = 0
    AND mp_0.day <= 123456
    AND mp_0.day > 123456 - 8
)
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE data.processed PARTITION (day = 123456)
SELECT
    *
FROM
  (SELECT m.*, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY bp ORDER BY RAND()) as rn FROM merged m) t
WHERE
  t.rn <= 1000
```

I'm sampling data by bp, so I'm taking 1000 random rows for each bp. Additionally, the table is partitioned by day, so this query takes data for 8 days.

Comment: There is no day column returned in the query, you inserting 1000 random 8 day records into single day partition, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases self joins can be replaced with aggregation or analytic functions. Consider replacing joins with case statements and aggregation, this will perform much better. Like this:

```
WITH merged AS (
SELECT
    bp,
    name,
    country,
    day,

    0 pos_0, --pos_0 is always=0, pos_1=1... Does it makes sense to have these constants?
    max(case when pos=0 then min_p end) AS min_p_0,
    max(case when pos=0 then max_p end) AS max_p_0,

    1 pos_1, 
    max(case when pos=1 then min_p end) AS min_p_1,
    max(case when pos=1 then max_p end) AS max_p_1,

    2 pos_2, 
    max(case when pos=2 then min_p end) AS min_p_2,
    max(case when pos=2 then max_p end) AS max_p_2,

    ...

    and so on ...

FROM
    data.customers c

WHERE
        c.day <= 123456
    AND c.day > 123456 - 8
GROUP BY     
    bp,
    name,
    country,
    day
)
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE data.processed PARTITION (day = 123456)
SELECT
    * --probably you need to list columns without `day` here, because in the original query you have no `day` column
FROM
  (SELECT m.*, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY bp order by RAND()) as rn 
     FROM merged m
    WHERE rand() <= 0.001 --filter some records before row_number, this may help to improve performance, check it please and adjust 
  ) t
WHERE
  t.rn <= 1000
```

Do you really need `order by RAND()` in the `row_number`? **row_number without order by** will assign numbers randomly inside bp partition. Without `order by rand()` it will perform faster. Use `order by rand()` if you really need these 1000 records to be "more random" than without `order by rand()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your approach looks interesting, to join without joins. The thing is, I'm using this as input to a ML algorithm, where all of these represent features, so I need to have them all in "one row" as they represent a single example for training. About the RAND() part, I do need that sample is random, as I've read if you do LIMIT quite often you'll get same rows in Hive, most likely based on position in the file. I guess it's the same thing with row_number, if you don't do order by rand. I need a different sample each run.

Comment: @Marko Is it something wrong with case+aggregation approach? It should work the same as your joins